# How to load files and all result put in separate files in bash?

Tags: bash, parallel.foreach

I have a few *.afa format files. I need to delete gaps from them, and i have a tool for that.
It's a fac.
The command in fac is :

```
fac -g inputFile.afa outputFile.afa
```

And it's working perfectly. But now I need to automatically process 100xx files, and I want to script it. But in the result, I need to have an unchanged input file and result in file witch R in first place in the file name.
For example:

```
Before:
1.afa 30kb
2.afa 30kb
3.afa 40kb

After:
1.afa 30kb
R1.afa 15kb
2.afa 30kb
R2.afa 15kb
3.afa 40kb
R3.afa 20kb
```

Bash is unfamiliar to me. I know I should learn it, and I will, but I need result fast.
Now I just write this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.afa | parallel "fac -g {} >{R.}.afa"
```

But:
1. I can't write a proper regex to print result in a new file in R in the first letter
2. Only the last result is saved in one file. That's don't generate a result for each file.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a single line within bash shell assuming you're in the folder where all the `.afa` files are:

```
l=($(ls *.afa)); for f in ${l[@]}; do fac -g $f "R$f"; done
# Should also work without "" around R$f.
```

As @codeforester pointed out, this is better (safer):

```
for f in *.afa; do fac -g $f "R$f"; done
```

This can be expanded as:

```
l=(*.afa) # bash array for all .afa files.
for f in ${l[@]}; do # loop over array
    fac -g $f R$f; # Run original command for each $f
done
```

Comment: It is not good to parse the output of `ls`.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.  You could write the loop simply as: `for f in *.afa; do fac -g "$f" R"$f"; done`.  Remember to put the variable in double quotes to prevent word splitting and globbing.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you can't write the correct regex for `parallel` is that there's no regex involved. `{}` is simply replaced with the quoted name. If you want to prepend `R` it's just `R{}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
parallel "fac -g {} R{}" ::: *.afa
```

Since piping from `ls` is not considered good practice, this example uses glob expansion instead.